# Returning empty queryset when used __startswith(or similar kind) while querying mogodb through parsepy

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset, parsepy

I am accessing **mongodb** through **parsepy** in my **django application**. I have a name field in my db collection. I'm trying to get those name fields which match my query string.

**For example, if I have these values--> food, folk, form, fill, filled, dust**

If I query **fo** I should get **food, folk, form**.

If I query **fi** I should get **fill, filled**

I found that `CollectionName.Query.filter(name__startswith=query)` could do that. But unfortunately that is giving me **empty queryset**.

I tried it with `CollectionName.Query.filter(name=ExactNameInDB)` like `CollectionName.Query.filter(name='food')` and it returned me the collection object with that name as the queryset.

I even tried `name__contains` as keyword argument but that didn't work. This one is bugging me since a long time. Please help me. If you think that this explanation isn't enough, I can elaborate the context more.

Comment: Are you sure that `__startswith` obtained `'fo'`? Did you hardcode that value?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem No, __startswith is returning empty queryset. I harcoded `collectionName.Query.filter(name="food")` and that worked fine. I am using [parsepy wrapper](https://github.com/milesrichardson/ParsePy).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just tried hardcoding the name to confirm whether it is sucessfully hitting db(ParsePy) or not.